# Angular 2 Can't able to add nested component inside a component

Tags: angular

Am trying to add a component inside another component, am getting an error in form builder group as.

- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined
- Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

am posting my full code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aNOiLjI9PYiCn81KFcSW) for your reference, please do help me to resolve this issue, sorry if it is a duplicated issue

**Interface**

```
export interface Customer {
    name: string;
    addressess: Address[];

}

export interface Address {
    street: string;
    postcode: string;

}

export interface ExtraFields {
  DOB:string;
  Designation:string;
         otherfields: ExtraFields[];
}
```

Componenet

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'address',
    templateUrl: 'address.component.html',
})
export class AddressComponent {
    @Input('group')
    public adressForm: FormGroup;
    private _fb: FormBuilder
    constructor(){}


    ngOnInit() {
        this.adressForm = this._fb.group({
            extraspaces: this._fb.array([])
        });

        // add address
        this.addextraField();

        /* subscribe to addresses value changes */
        // this.myForm.controls['addresses'].valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        //   console.log(x);
        // })
    }


    initextraField() {
        return this._fb.group({
            dob: ['', Validators.required],
            designation: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    addextraField() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.adressForm.controls['extraspaces'];
        const addrCtrl = this.initextraField();

        control.push(addrCtrl);
    }

    // removeAddress(i: number) {
    //     const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
    //     control.removeAt(i);
    // }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div [formGroup]="adressForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street">
        <small [hidden]="adressForm.controls.street.valid" class="text-danger">
            Street is required
        </small>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>postcode</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
    </div>
         <div class="margin-20">
          <a (click)="addextraField()" style="cursor: default">
            Add +
          </a>
        </div>

            <div formArrayName="extraspaces">
          <div *ngFor="let ext of adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Address {{i + 1}}</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
              <extrafield [extragroup]="adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls[i]"></extrafield>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues in the AddressComponent are the cause of the aforementioned errors:

1. `_fb` variable is not injected
2. FormBuilder and Validators are not imported
3. Incorrect addressForm model configuration

Basically, once you import the required types

`import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';`

inject FormBuilder

`constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){}`

and define the FormGroup correctly

`this.adressForm = this._fb.group({
            street: [''],
            postcode: [''],
            extraspaces: this._fb.array([])
});`

everything will work just fine.

Check the modified plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wjj6FGFK1esqRQh5oEGY?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot for correcting mistakes, am having one more issue, I cant able to get the field values in below JSON representations